# I am getting compile error at line number 5 as Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token 'Map'

Tags: apex

```apex
public static void  updateCatAndRankForTournaments(final Map<Id, Tournament_Entry__c> oldEntries, Map<Id, Tournament_Entry__c> newEntries) {
    Map<Id, List<Tournament_Entry__c>> parentToChildren = new Map<Id, List<Tournament_Entry__c>>();
    List<Tournament_Entry__c> tEntriesExistingTourTobeUpdate = new List<Tournament_Entry__c>();
    for (Tournament_Entry__c newTournamentEntry : newEntries.values()) {
        Tournament_Entry__c oldTournamentEntry = oldEntries.get(newTournamentEntry.Id);
        for (Tournament_Entry__c tEnties : Map<Id, Tournament_Entry__c> catRankTobeChangedlst  = new Map<Id, Tournament_Entry__c> ([SELECT Player_Full_Name__c, Player_Name__c,   Tour_Membership__c, Category_Rank__c, Category__c 
                FROM Tournament_Entry__c 
                WHERE ID != : newTournamentEntry.Id   //This entry should not be updated as it is done on the UpdateCategoryAndRank popup.
                AND Category__c = :newTournamentEntry.Category__c
                AND Category_Rank__c >= :newTournamentEntry.Category_Rank__c    //Ranks should add +1 only for the players below this rank. NOT above. That is the difference between the promoted player's cat change ond just tournament cat change.
                AND Player_Full_Name__c != 'Unallocated Player'
                AND Status__c NOT IN ('Withdrawn' , 'Moved') 
                ORDER BY Count__c ASC  ]);) {
            if (!parentToChildren.containsKey(tEnties.Tournament_Entry__c))
                parentToChildren.put(tEnties.Tournament_Entry__c, new List<Tournament_Entry__c>());
            parentToChildren.get(tEnties.Tournament_Entry__c).add(tEnties);
        }
        System.debug('Tour entries to be updated NUMBERS >>>>>>>>>>>>>' +catRankTobeChangedlst.size());
        //Change the rank in the current tournament and category only
        for (Tournament_Entry__c newTournamentEntry : newEntries.values()) {
            for(Tournament_Entry__c catRankTobeChanged : catRankTobeChangedlst.values())
                if (newTournamentEntry.Category__c != oldTournamentEntry.Category__c || newTournamentEntry.Category_Rank__c != oldTournamentEntry.Category_Rank__c) {
                    catRankTobeChanged.Category_Rank__c += 1 ;
                    System.debug('Tour entries to be updated ' + catRankTobeChanged.Player_Full_Name__c+ ' to a new rank ' +catRankTobeChanged.Category_Rank__c);
                    tEntriesExistingTourTobeUpdate.add(catRankTobeChanged);       //Add all of the entries except the current player whose entry is going to change. Don't update tour membership
                }           
                isFirstTimeUpdateCatRank  = false; //to avoid the recursion.
                update tEntriesExistingTourTobeUpdate;
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange! In addition to @Mariia's answer, I would advise *always* using curly braces to explicitly define your `if` block code, even if you only have one line of code within it. This makes it [1] Easier for everyone (including a future you) to read & understand, and [2] If later a 2nd line of code needs to be added within the `if`, many times a line is just indented and added, not realizing that there are no braces, which means that line is not really within the `if` statement. It is hard to tell if you want both lines inside the `if` found in your 2nd 'for' loop

Answer (score 3):

You've got a problem in the second for-loop, you have just put variable definition straight into for-loop. Move it out of the loop as a defined variable:

```
Map<Id, Tournament_Entry__c> catRankTobeChangedlst = new Map<Id, Tournament_Entry__c> ([SELECT Player_Full_Name__c, Player_Name__c,   Tour_Membership__c, Category_Rank__c, Category__c 
                FROM Tournament_Entry__c 
                WHERE ID != : newTournamentEntry.Id   //This entry should not be updated as it is done on the UpdateCategoryAndRank popup.
                AND Category__c = :newTournamentEntry.Category__c
                AND Category_Rank__c >= :newTournamentEntry.Category_Rank__c    //Ranks should add +1 only for the players below this rank. NOT above. That is the difference between the promoted player's cat change ond just tournament cat change.
                AND Player_Full_Name__c != 'Unallocated Player'
                AND Status__c NOT IN ('Withdrawn' , 'Moved') 
                ORDER BY Count__c ASC  ]);
for (Tournament_Entry__c tEnties : catRankTobeChangedlst.values()) {
    //...
}
```

Also it is a bad practice to perform SOQL queries inside the loop.